# Twitter api response unreadable

Tags: encoding, asp-classic, twitter

We have been using twitter api for a while now but suddenly it stopped working. Tracing it back it seems that the response from the `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` request is unreadable by ASP vbscript.

Even a simple GET request to a page turns into invalid charactors. Opening https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token in a browser will show a string "Failed to validate oauth signature and token". When I try to get the same thing in ASP it returns unreadable data.

```
<% @LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<%
Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", false
objXMLHTTP.send ""

Response.Write "<pre>"
Response.Write objXMLHTTP.responseText
Response.Write "<hr>"
Response.Write objXMLHTTP.getAllResponseHeaders()
Response.Write "</pre>"
%>
```

output is:

```
?
------
Date: Thu, 06 Dec 2012 09:12:17 GMT
Status: 401 Unauthorized
X-MID: caa889032d29f5316a855dcadd748211ed4ee276
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Last-Modified: Thu, 06 Dec 2012 09:12:16 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-Transaction: dd71c8da0813a966
Expires: Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT
X-Runtime: 0.02056
Set-Cookie: k=10.36.75.125.1354785136971277; path=/; expires=Thu, 13-Dec-12 09:12:16 GMT; domain=.twitter.com
Set-Cookie: guest_id=v1%3A135478513698331395; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; expires=Sat, 06-Dec-2014 21:12:16 GMT
Set-Cookie: _twitter_sess=BAh7CDoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCFihfG87ASIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29u%250AdHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoHaWQiJTMx%250AMzI0YjhkNDc4YmQ4MDExMjlhNTI2NWU5OTAxNDVi--97206a42b05d8cb85fbd88ccd9ccb8aaca39ebef; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 62
Server: tfe
```

the ? is infact a string with more charactors but cannot be handled because it contains a CHR(0).

Now I figured it might be because of the `Content-Encoding: gzip`, but even when sending an `objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "none"` (or any other format) it returns the same.

Anybody has any idea what I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking at this for hours now and just after asking I find the awnser! Twitter API requires a user-agent to be sent a long with the request. So it was as simple as:

```
Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", false
objXMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "something"
objXMLHTTP.send()
```