# Getting bad response or nothing at all from Twitter

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

so I don't know what's happening, but I'm using both Abraham Williams and Math Harris' libraries, both updated to reflect the new 1.1 rest API.
Everything was working fine until a couple of days ago, when twitter started to give strange error messages I have never seen before, such as NULL or 0. When I try to connect with twitter to authorize again my own app, after an the eternity it gets to connect, all I get is "NULL Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.". 
Is this happening to me only? I have seen that the API has had issues these days, but not today they say. 
I don't know what the problem can be. Twitter starts to be embarassingly difficult to manage, for one who is not a professional developer at least.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions to resolve this.

EDIT: I have tried a good number of libraries now and what was working until a week ago isn't working now. Neither twitteroauth nor thmOauth work anymore and I'd pay to know the reason. The black-out has been going on for a week now and my users might have started to realize. The Twitter support, contacted, says that everything is fine on their side. I have tried everything I think, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in the end I figured out. Just a matter of shared IP blacklisted. Thanks for your suggestion, which might have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the twitter api in `ASP` code. The problem was that the 'user-agent' header had to be sent with the request. If you leave it out it will give strange results. See [the ASP question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740491/twitter-api-response-unreadable)

So make sure your request to the api includes the `user-agent` header, doesnt matter what the value is.

Comment: thanks! Unfortunately even if I fill in the user agent with the App name I get the same 0 error code. I even tried to set  `'curl_ssl_verifypeer'        => false,` but it's not helping...